# Why doesn't BinaryFormatter throw an exception after a new property is added?

Tags: c#, exception, binaryformatter

I have a class defined as follows:

```
[Serializable]
class C
{
  String str { get; set; }
  int num { get; set; }
}
```

I've serialized it into a file with BinaryFormatter. Then I've changed the class as shown below.

```
[Serializable]
class C
{
  String str { get; set; }
  int num { get; set; }
  int num2 { get; set; }
}
```

However, upon deserialization instead of throwing an exception the formatter sets num2 to zero. Is there a way to require it to throw?

Comment: there is [version tolerant serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752(v=vs.110).aspx) to refer to; your question is interesting as you want the opposite, *not* ignoring new class members. btw. deserialization does not set `num2`, it just keeps its initial value, which is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I've figured out that to change the behavior I could set

```
formatter.AssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full;
```

Although it's probably an overkill.